# Need Help! Upgraded to a new PC and from Visual Studio 2008 to 2013. ODBC Data Connections are Broken in all my projects

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, odbc, ibm-midrange

I have been using Visual studio 2008 to create some basic search apps where I work. In 2008 I could just go to "add new datasource", select ODBC connection and select my iSeries Access ODBC driver, Select the tables I wanted, then drag them onto a DataGridView in my windows form. Now when I go to do this in VS 2013 the second I click on one of my ODBC connections the Add datasource window either just disappears or I get an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". Is there a difference in the way Visual studio 2008 handles odbc connections vs Visual Studio 2013?

I am sure this is something simple that I am missing, But i really really need these connections to work. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

*edit, I have tried a complete uninstall and reinstall of VS 2013 and I still have the same problem. Visual Studio 2008 continues to work without issue.

Comment: `Upgraded to a new PC` - does that PC have the ODBC sources, and do they have the same bitness (32 or 64)?

Comment: Yes it does, i created the 32 bit versions by launching odbcad from the SYSWOW64 folder. Also I am having the same issue when starting a new project from scratch as well. I can import the table data into MS excel just fine. The only thing different on this new PC is Visual studio 2013 vs 2008

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a new PC, the data source may not be defined.  check in your PC for Admin Tools > ODBC data sources > AS400 ODBC driver >Configure > Server Tab > Lib list.  Your libraries you want to access may not be listed in your Lib list.